# Modal Dialog unexpected redirect

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I follow these steps:

1) Open file permissions page in modal dialog clicking "Document Permissions" button on the Ribbon menu. The next page is opened:
[image]

2) Then I click "Modify" -> "Edit User Permissions" and the next page is opened as modal dialog.
[image]

3) After that I click "OK" button on the current model dialog. This dialog is closed successfully and then my modal dialog which was opened at first step is redirected to the list where I selected current item. See picture below:
[image]

But I want only refresh my model dialog opened at first step, when I click "OK" button on the second model dialog. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this trouble. I create custom action which has the same id as system button, then set callback and call `location.reload(true)` in that callback. here is my code:

```
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Permission.Modify"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RequireSiteAdministrator="false" >
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Permission.Modify.EditUsrPerm">
      <Button
        Id="Ribbon.Permission.Modify.EditUsrPerm"
        Command="EditItemPermission"
        Sequence="11"
        Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-128" Image16by16Left="-192"
        Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-96" Image32by32Left="-384"
        LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_EditUsrPerm;"
        Alt="$Resources:core,cui_EditUsrPerm;"
        ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_EditUsrPermToolTipTitle;"
        ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_EditUsrPermToolTip;"
        TemplateAlias="o1"
      />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="EditItemPermission"
      EnabledScript="javascript: 
            function IsEntriesSelected()
            {
                // form.PrincipalId and form.PrincipalName locate in /_layouts/User.aspx
                var form = document.forms.aspnetForm;
                  var elemId = form.PrincipalId;
                  var elemName = form.PrincipalName;

                  if (elemId == null)
                      return false;

                  var len = elemId.length;
                  if (len == null)
                  {
                        if(elemId.checked)
                            return true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        for (var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++)
                        {
                            if (elemId[i].checked)
                                return true;
                        }
                   }
              }

            IsEntriesSelected();"
      CommandAction= "javascript:

            function SetRolesFromModalDialog()
            {
               // this function locate in /_layouts/User.aspx
               var selected = GetSelectedPrincipals();
                 var ids = selected.strIds;

               // strAclObject - this variable locate in /_layouts/User.aspx
               var options =
                {
                    url:'/_layouts/editprms.aspx?obj=' + strAclObject + '&amp;sel=' + escapeProperly(ids),
                    allowMaximize: false,
                    showClose: true,
                    showMaximized: false,
                    dialogReturnValueCallback: CallBack 
                };

               SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }

            function CallBack(dialogResult, retValue)
            {
                if(dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) 
                     location.reload(true);
            }

            SetRolesFromModalDialog();"
    />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```